# GBQ - Merge cells of a column across rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data table that looks like this

```
start_date | end_date | string

date x   |  date y   |  apple

date x  |   date y  |   orange

date z  |   date y   |  grape
```

I want to merge the string column if the start_date and end_date are the same across rows. So out put would look like this

```
start_date | end_date | string

date x   |  date y  | apple/orange

date z   |  date y |  grape
```

I am using Google big query SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: String_Agg or Group_Concat (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg)

Comment: as FYI: `STRING_AGG()` is for BQ Standard SQL and `GROUP_CONCAT()` is for BQ Legacy SQL. BigQuery Team strongly recommends using Standard dialect - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start_date, end_date, STRING_AGG(str, '/') str
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
select start_date, end_date, GROUP_CONCAT(string) as string
from table t
group by start_date, end_date;
```